# Should I run the init process inside a Docker container or not?

Tags: docker, init

I recently researched some best practises about Docker and came across different opinions on how or if to handle the init process.

As pointed out [here](http://crosbymichael.com/dockerfile-best-practices-take-2.html), the init process should **not** be run at all. I can follow the thought that a container should model a single process and not the whole OS.

On the other hand as described [here](https://phusion.github.io/baseimage-docker) there can be problems if I just ignore the basic OS services like syslog.

As often there is maybe no absolute answer on how to handle these cases. Can you share some experiences or more insights about this topic? For me both approached seem legit.

Comment: I don't see how this is an on topic programming question.

Answer (score 11):

> As often there is maybe no absolute answer on how to handle these
>   cases. Can you share some experiences or more insights about this
>   topic? For me both approached seem legit.

Spot on.  There is no absolute answer to this question.

Now, having said that, I think that there are substantial advantages
to the single-process-per-container model, because that really
encourages you to create containers that are *composable* (like lego
blocks: you can put them together in different combinations to solve a
problem) and that are *scalable* (you can spin up more instances of a
particular service without too much effort).  By not doing crazy
things like running an ssh daemon inside your container, you are
discouraged from editing things "in place" and will -- hopefully -- be
more likely to rely on Dockerfiles to generate your images, which
leads to a much more robust, reproducible process.

On the other hand, there are some applications that don't lend
themselves well to this model.  For example, if you have an
application that forks lots of child processes and doesn't properly
`wait()` for them, you end up with a collection of zombie processes.
You can run a full-blown `init` process to solve this particular
problem, or you can run something simple [like
this](https://github.com/larsks/reaper) (disclaimer: I wrote that) [or
this](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker/blob/master/image/bin/my_init).

Some applications are just really tightly coupled, and while it's
possible to run them in separate containers through liberal
application of Docker volumes and `--net=container:...`, it's easier
just to let them run in the same container.

Logging in Docker is particular challenging.  Running *some* sort of
log collector inside a container along with your application can be
one solution to that problem, but there are other solutions, too.
[Logspout](https://github.com/gliderlabs/logspout) is an interesting
one, but I have also been looking at running [systemd](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) inside
containers in order to make use of `journald` for logging.  So, while
I am still running one *application* process per container, I also
have an `init` process, and a `journald` process.

So, ultimately, it really depends on the situation: both on your needs
and the needs of the particular application you are trying to run.
Even in situations where a single *process* per container isn't
possible, designing containers to offer a single *service* still
confers many of the advantages I mentioned in the first paragraph.